# Custom ListView In Fragment - The Constructor Is Undefined

Tags: android, listview

I'm learning about PageSlider and would like to implement ListViews in my slide fragments, my code is as follows but gives an error on CustomAdapter:

```
The constructor FragmentA.CustomAdapter(FragmentA, String[], String[], int[]) is undefined.
```

I can add a TextView however the ListView returns an error as described above.

FragmentA:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    String [] arrayName;
    String [] arrayDescription;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};

    ListView lv;

    public FragmentA() {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

            ListView lv =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

            CustomeAdapter adapter = new CustomeAdapter (this, arrayName, arrayDescription, images);    //Error: The constructor FragmentA.CustomAdapter(FragmentA, String[], String[], int[]) is undefined

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            return view;

    }
```

CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
    {
    Context context;
    String[] arraynames;
    String[] arrayDescription;
    int[] images;
    CustomeAdapter(Context c, String [] name, String [] description, int img[])
    {
        super(c, R.layout.activity_lv_single, R.id.textname, name);
        this.context=c;
        this.arraynames=name;
        this.arrayDescription=description;
        this.images=img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lv_single, parent, false)
        }

        TextView tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        TextView tvDescription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        tvName.setText(arrayNames[position]);
        tvDescription.setText(arrayDescription[position]);
        ivImage.(images[positionl

        return rowView;

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) class doesn't extend [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), you can't pass a Fragment to the adapter where it expects a Context.
Instead of `this`, just use `getActivity()`, since [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) extends [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html):

```
CustomeAdapter adapter = new CustomeAdapter (getActivity(), arrayName, arrayDescription, images);
```